# Jersey JSON parsing with root name of class name

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a pojo class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "project")
public class Project {

    private UUID id;
    private String label;
    private String name;

    //getters and setters
}
```

It accepts this as input if I try from postman.

```
{
    "label" : "label",
    "name" : "name"
}
```

But, I want it to accept values as

```
{
    "project" : {
        "label" : "label",
        "name" : "name"
    } 
}
```

My endpoint method is

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createProject(Project project) {

        log.info("createProject called." + project);
        if (project == null) {
            return Response.ok(false).build();
        }

        ps = new ProjectServiceImpl();
        return Response.ok(ps.createProject(project)).build();
    }
```

There are various other methods which are like this, like get all projects, where other party expects 'root-name' or 'class-name' like this at the start of json. I am stuck with things like this and it's slowing down my work. Please suggest me something or provide any source where I can read the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I think `SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` and `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` are configuration options that you are looking for.

Read more here:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features

Answer (score 0):

Please use @XmlRootElement instead of @XmlRootElement(name = "project") and try it out

Answer (score 0):

A good read if you are using **spring and consuming a rest service** - http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/